# Query Sharepoint Online using REST API and passing the query in the body (POST)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

The URL length limit is causing me issues when I call the end point `/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('ListName')/items`: if I have too many parameters, the URL length is too long and my request is not treated.

I know we can pass a CAML query to the endpoint `/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('ListName')/GetItems` in the body, but this endpoint is limited if we want to expand a lookup/user field. So I'm stuck with `/items`.

Is there a way to do a POST to `/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('ListName')/items` with passing the parameters in the body instead of passing them in the URL? If yes, how? I didn't find anything on the web about it…

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we can use the [`$batch` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis) to do it, even if it's not really the same, but I guess it will work… If someone knows another way, please share!

Note: for an unknown reason I have a `$batch` that returns `Invalid request.`, but if I pass the same URL to a normal request, then it works…